# React router, handle URL (instead of backend)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser-history

I've implemented the router and everything works (navigation etc.) but how can I make sure that when I want to go to http://myapp.dev/members that the url is handled by react (router)? When I type that URL in my browser now, nothing happens, because the /members doesnt exist (backend)

Comment: Isn't this just a matter of ensuring your browser serves these URLs from the web app?

Comment: what are you using for your backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to redirect your backend to wherever your react application is. `react-router` themselves have it in their [documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md). If you're on nginx, use a `try_files` rule to try, see if it exists, and if not, fire back to wherever your react app is.

The same goes for Apache using rewrite rules.

Both are actually very well documented within the doc.